# What is the best way to convert flat records into objects?

Tags: angularjs

I have a flashcard application in which I get a set of flashcard records from the server, then run through it in a ng-repeat loop. However, instead of looping through these flat records, I would like to loop through a collection of objects with methods that I can call, as I do in PHP.

Is there an "AngularJS" way to do this, and if not, what is the best method to do this so that I can e.g. load a collection of flashcard objects with my records and then use this collection in multiple views with ng-repeat?

**controller:**

```
mainApp.controller('browseController', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
    $http.get($rootScope.dataUrlPath, {
        params: {
            taskIdCode: 'getAllFlashcardsWithStacks'
        }
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.flashcards = data['flashcards'];
    });
});
```

**view:**

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <h1 class="pageTitle">Browse Flashcards</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="flashcard in flashcards">
        <div>{{flashcard.front}}</div>
        <div>{{flashcard.back}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <h1 class="pageTitle">Browse Flashcards</h1>
    <div ng-repeat="flashcard in flashcards">
        {{flashcard.displayAsRichInteractiveFlashcard()}}
    </div>
</div>
```

But if possible, I would like to do it "the Angular way" and this seems to be getting away from how Angular works.

**What is the best way to turn my records into a collection of rich objects so that I can access their rich methods from various views?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Yes**, there is an angular way to access the data in your ng-repeat, namely your flashcard, with methods you can call : by creating a custom directive.

Let's call that custom directive *my-flashcard-directive*.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-repeat="flashcard in flashcards">
    <my-flashcard-directive flashcard="flashcard"></my-flashcard-directive>
</div>
```

Then define your methods in your **`my-flashcard-directive`**

Your directive has access to `scope.flashcard` and can act on it at will.

**Directive**

```
myModule.directive('myFlashcardDirective', function() {
    return {
        scope: {
            flashcard: '='
        },
        restrict:'E',
        template:"<div>{{flashcard.displayAsRichInteractiveFlashcard() }}</div>",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
scope.flashcard.displayAsRichInteractiveFlashcard=function (){//whatever
       };
        }
    }
});
```

Your collection still has the same json-transportable, string properties.

However, your custom-built directive can now augment it as you wish.

Comment: From my phone: sorry for the poor presentation

Comment: Not having access to a proper keyboard, so no guarantee this will work out of the box. Should point you to the right direction, though.

Comment: Great, this got me going, thanks. One thing I had to add to get anything to appear was "restrict: 'E'".